# Automapper reverse map through a function

Tags: c#, automapper

In source Device.cs in simplification I have:

```
using Assisticant.Collections;

(...)

private ObservableList<Result> _results = new ObservableList<Result>();

public IEnumerable<Result> Results
{
   get { return _results; }
}

public void AddResult(Result result)
{
    _results.Add(result);
}
```

The destination DeviceDto.cs is:

```
public List<Result> Results { get; set; }
```

How should I make configuration for Automapper to make simple direct mapping from source to destination and at the same time reverse mapping of every element through `.AddResult(result)` function?
(I have to add elements this way due to used library purpose)

What should I add to:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Device, DeviceDto>().ReverseMap();
});

_mapper = new Mapper(config);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `ReverseMap()`, but configure the mapping from `DeviceDto` to `Device` explicitly.

Because `Device.Results` only defines a getter, it will be ignored by AutoMapper during the mapping step. Use the `AfterMap` method if you need to access source and destination at the same time.

```
using System.Linq;

var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Device, DeviceDto>();
    cfg.CreateMap<DeviceDto, Device>()
        .AfterMap((src, dst) => src.Results.Select(result => dst.AddResult(result)));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`AfterMap`](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Before-and-after-map-actions.html):

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(
    cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<Device, DeviceDto>()
            .ReverseMap()
                .AfterMap((src, dest) =>
                { 
                    foreach (Result result in src.Results)
                    {
                        dest.AddResult(result);
                    }
                });
    });
```